# Error creating bean with name 'restHandlerMapping' Missing path mapping. bean 'repositoryController' must be mapped to a non-empty path

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, vue.js

Trying to write api for authorization jwt+csrf, but I get an error.
How to fix it?
thanks in advance

**Error:**

> Error creating bean with name 'restHandlerMapping' defined in class
>   path resource
>   [org/springframework/data/rest/webmvc/config/RepositoryRestMvcConfiguration.class]:
>   Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to
>   instantiate
>   [org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.support.DelegatingHandlerMapping]:
>   Factory method 'restHandlerMapping' threw exception; nested exception
>   is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Missing path mapping. Handler
>   method
>   'org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.RepositoryController#optionsForRepositories()'
>   in bean 'repositoryController' must be mapped to a non-empty path. If
>   you wish to map to all paths, please map explicitly to /** or **.

**Full terminal output:**

```java
2019-04-06 00:37:35.103  WARN 24654 --- [  restartedMain] ConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'restHandlerMapping' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/data/rest/webmvc/config/RepositoryRestMvcConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.support.DelegatingHandlerMapping]: Factory method 'restHandlerMapping' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Missing path mapping. Handler method 'org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.RepositoryController#optionsForRepositories()' in bean 'repositoryController' must be mapped to a non-empty path. If you wish to map to all paths, please map explicitly to "/**" or "**".
2019-04-06 00:37:35.124  INFO 24654 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.s.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor  : Shutting down ExecutorService 'applicationTaskExecutor'
2019-04-06 00:37:35.126  INFO 24654 --- [  restartedMain] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Closing JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2019-04-06 00:37:35.129  INFO 24654 --- [  restartedMain] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Shutdown initiated...
2019-04-06 00:37:35.138  INFO 24654 --- [  restartedMain] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Shutdown completed.
2019-04-06 00:37:35.141  INFO 24654 --- [  restartedMain] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Stopping service [Tomcat]
2019-04-06 00:37:35.160  INFO 24654 --- [  restartedMain] ConditionEvaluationReportLoggingListener : 

Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2019-04-06 00:37:35.165 ERROR 24654 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed

org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'restHandlerMapping' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/data/rest/webmvc/config/RepositoryRestMvcConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.support.DelegatingHandlerMapping]: Factory method 'restHandlerMapping' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Missing path mapping. Handler method 'org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.RepositoryController#optionsForRepositories()' in bean 'repositoryController' must be mapped to a non-empty path. If you wish to map to all paths, please map explicitly to "/**" or "**".
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:638) ~[spring-beans-5.2.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:5.2.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:468) ~[spring-beans-5.2.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:5.2.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1325) ~[spring-beans-5.2.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:5.2.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1164) ~[spring-beans-5.2.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:5.2.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:555) ~[spring-beans-5.2.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:5.2.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:515) ~[spring-beans-5.2.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:5.2.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:320) ~[spring-beans-5.2.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:5.2.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222) ~[spring-beans-5.2.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:5.2.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:318) ~[spring-beans-5.2.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:5.2.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199) ~[spring-beans-5.2.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:5.2.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:866) ~[spring-beans-5.2.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:5.2.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:877) ~[spring-context-5.2.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:5.2.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:549) ~[spring-context-5.2.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:5.2.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:142) ~[spring-boot-2.2.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:2.2.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:785) ~[spring-boot-2.2.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:2.2.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:407) ~[spring-boot-2.2.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:2.2.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:322) ~[spring-boot-2.2.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:2.2.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1278) ~[spring-boot-2.2.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:2.2.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1266) ~[spring-boot-2.2.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:2.2.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
        at com.sandr1x.quizspringvue.QuizSpringVueApplication.main(QuizSpringVueApplication.java:9) ~[main/:na]
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566) ~[na:na]
        at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:49) ~[spring-boot-devtools-2.2.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:2.2.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.support.DelegatingHandlerMapping]: Factory method 'restHandlerMapping' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Missing path mapping. Handler method 'org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.RepositoryController#optionsForRepositories()' in bean 'repositoryController' must be mapped to a non-empty path. If you wish to map to all paths, please map explicitly to "/**" or "**".
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:185) ~[spring-beans-5.2.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:5.2.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:633) ~[spring-beans-5.2.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:5.2.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
        ... 24 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Missing path mapping. Handler method 'org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.RepositoryController#optionsForRepositories()' in bean 'repositoryController' must be mapped to a non-empty path. If you wish to map to all paths, please map explicitly to "/**" or "**".
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractHandlerMethodMapping$MappingRegistry.validateMethodMapping(AbstractHandlerMethodMapping.java:622) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:5.2.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractHandlerMethodMapping$MappingRegistry.register(AbstractHandlerMethodMapping.java:592) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:5.2.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractHandlerMethodMapping.registerHandlerMethod(AbstractHandlerMethodMapping.java:314) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:5.2.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractHandlerMethodMapping.lambda$detectHandlerMethods$1(AbstractHandlerMethodMapping.java:284) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:5.2.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
        at java.base/java.util.LinkedHashMap.forEach(LinkedHashMap.java:684) ~[na:na]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractHandlerMethodMapping.detectHandlerMethods(AbstractHandlerMethodMapping.java:282) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:5.2.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractHandlerMethodMapping.processCandidateBean(AbstractHandlerMethodMapping.java:254) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:5.2.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractHandlerMethodMapping.initHandlerMethods(AbstractHandlerMethodMapping.java:213) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:5.2.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractHandlerMethodMapping.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractHandlerMethodMapping.java:201) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:5.2.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping.afterPropertiesSet(RequestMappingHandlerMapping.java:164) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:5.2.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
        at org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.BasePathAwareHandlerMapping.afterPropertiesSet(BasePathAwareHandlerMapping.java:194) ~[spring-data-rest-webmvc-3.2.0.M2.jar:3.2.0.M2]
        at org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.config.RepositoryRestMvcConfiguration.restHandlerMapping(RepositoryRestMvcConfiguration.java:588) ~[spring-data-rest-webmvc-3.2.0.M2.jar:3.2.0.M2]
        at org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.config.RepositoryRestMvcConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$1be339be.CGLIB$restHandlerMapping$28(<generated>) ~[spring-data-rest-webmvc-3.2.0.M2.jar:3.2.0.M2]
        at org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.config.RepositoryRestMvcConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$1be339be$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$84f2d0e6.invoke(<generated>) ~[spring-data-rest-webmvc-3.2.0.M2.jar:3.2.0.M2]
        at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invokeSuper(MethodProxy.java:244) ~[spring-core-5.2.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:5.2.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:363) ~[spring-context-5.2.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:5.2.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
        at org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.config.RepositoryRestMvcConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$1be339be.restHandlerMapping(<generated>) ~[spring-data-rest-webmvc-3.2.0.M2.jar:3.2.0.M2]
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566) ~[na:na]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:154) ~[spring-beans-5.2.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:5.2.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
        ... 25 common frames omitted
```

**WebSecurityConfig.java**

```java
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    @Autowired
    UserDetailsServiceImpl userDetailsService;

    @Autowired
    private JwtAuthEntryPoint unauthorizedHandler;

    @Bean
    CorsConfigurationSource corsConfigurationSource() {
        CorsConfiguration config = new CorsConfiguration();
        config.setAllowCredentials(true);
        config.setAllowedOrigins(Arrays.asList("http://localhost:8080"));
        config.addAllowedHeader("*");
        config.addAllowedMethod("*");
        UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
        source.registerCorsConfiguration("/api/auth/**", config);
        return source;
    }

    @Bean
    public JwtAuthTokenFilter authenticationJwtTokenFilter() {
        return new JwtAuthTokenFilter();
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder authenticationManagerBuilder) throws Exception {
        authenticationManagerBuilder
                .userDetailsService(userDetailsService)
                .passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
    }

    @Bean
    @Override
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
        return super.authenticationManagerBean();
    }

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .cors()
            .and()
                .csrf()
                    .ignoringAntMatchers("/api/auth/signin")
                    .csrfTokenRepository(CookieCsrfTokenRepository.withHttpOnlyFalse())
            .and()
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/api/auth/**").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
            .and()
                .exceptionHandling()
                .authenticationEntryPoint(unauthorizedHandler)
            .and()
                .sessionManagement()
                .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
            .and()
                .addFilterBefore(authenticationJwtTokenFilter(), UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);
    }
}
```

**API**

```java
package com.sandr1x.quizspringvue.controller;

import com.sandr1x.quizspringvue.message.request.LoginForm;
import com.sandr1x.quizspringvue.message.request.SignUpForm;
import com.sandr1x.quizspringvue.message.response.JwtResponse;
import com.sandr1x.quizspringvue.model.Role;
import com.sandr1x.quizspringvue.model.RoleName;
import com.sandr1x.quizspringvue.model.User;
import com.sandr1x.quizspringvue.repository.RoleRepository;
import com.sandr1x.quizspringvue.repository.UserRepository;
import com.sandr1x.quizspringvue.security.jwt.JwtProvider;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationManager;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken;
import org.springframework.security.core.Authentication;
import org.springframework.security.core.context.SecurityContextHolder;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.password.PasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.CrossOrigin;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import javax.validation.Valid;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;

@CrossOrigin(origins = "*", maxAge = 3600)
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/auth")
public class AuthRestAPIs {

    @Autowired
    AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;

    @Autowired
    UserRepository userRepository;

    @Autowired
    RoleRepository roleRepository;

    @Autowired
    PasswordEncoder encoder;

    @Autowired
    JwtProvider jwtProvider;

    @PostMapping("/signin")
    public ResponseEntity<?> authenticateUser(@Valid @RequestBody LoginForm loginRequest) {
        Authentication authentication = authenticationManager.authenticate(
                new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(
                        loginRequest.getUsername(),
                        loginRequest.getPassword()
                )
        );

        SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authentication);

        String jwt = jwtProvider.generateJwtToken(authentication);
        return ResponseEntity.ok(new JwtResponse(jwt));
    }

    @PostMapping("/signup")
    public ResponseEntity<String> registerUser(@Valid @RequestBody SignUpForm signUpRequest) {
        if(userRepository.existsByUsername(signUpRequest.getUsername())) {
            return new ResponseEntity<String>("Fail -> Username is already taken!",
                    HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
        }

        if(userRepository.existsByEmail(signUpRequest.getEmail())) {
            return new ResponseEntity<String>("Fail -> Email is already in use!",
                    HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
        }

        User user = new User(signUpRequest.getUsername(),
                signUpRequest.getEmail(), encoder.encode(signUpRequest.getPassword()));

        Set<String> strRoles = signUpRequest.getRole();
        Set<Role> roles = new HashSet<>();

        strRoles.forEach(role -> {
            switch(role) {
                case "admin":
                    Role adminRole = roleRepository.findByName(RoleName.ROLE_ADMIN)
                    .orElseThrow(() -> new RuntimeException("Fail! -> Cause: User Role not find."));
                    roles.add(adminRole);

                    break;
                case "otherRole":
                    //

                    break;
                default:
                    Role userRole = roleRepository.findByName(RoleName.ROLE_USER)
                    .orElseThrow(() -> new RuntimeException("Fail! -> Cause: User Role not find."));
                    roles.add(userRole);
            }
        });

        user.setRoles(roles);
        userRepository.save(user);

        return ResponseEntity.ok().body("User registered successfully!");
    }
}
```

Comment: hi! edited your tags :) Java is not JavaScript

Comment: it looks like a bug in spring components, but I see that you are using spring-boot snapshot builds... Maybe try to switch to a 2.2.0.M1 and see if it works?

Answer (score 0):

This happened to me when I accidentally defined two controller methods for the same request method and endpoint.

Answer (score -1):

I confirm the problem is the version of spring boot I have.

Just change the version to 2.2.0.M1 and it will work.